# VC warning 4365 seems to be inconsistent

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings

My question is: why does VC emit warning 4365 for only one of the commented lines below, and not the other?

```
#pragma warning(1: 4365)

void test1(const unsigned short) {}

unsigned short test2() { return 0; }

int main()
{
    const unsigned short a = 0;
    const unsigned short b = 0;
    test1(a + b);       // This line gives no warning
    test1(test2() + b); // This line gives C4365
    return 0;
}
```

Tested under VS2010 and VS2012 Express.

For reference, the full warning text is this:

```
warning C4365: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'const unsigned short', signed/unsigned mismatch
```

Using Clang 3.3 (through Clang-Win32 and ClangVSx), no warnings are reported in this code (except of course the unknown pragma).

Comment: Warning C4365 is signed/unsigned mismatch, so it shouldn't apply to either of those lines, should it?

Comment: Exactly my thinking! There must be some strange integer promotion going on, but not consistently. I'm curious as to why there's any difference between what gets promoted on each of those two lines. (added warning text to the question so people don't have to look it up like you did!)

Comment: @Roger - C4265 is "conversion from 'type_1' to 'type_2', signed/unsigned mismatch". C4018 is the warning about signed/unsigned comparisons.

Comment: Another interesting bit of info - the warning in question is only issued when compiling this code as C++, not as C. Also, if either `a` or `b` are not `const`, the error is issued for the `test1(a + b);` line as well. So the key is C++ constness, not using the restful of a function.

Comment: VC seems to apply this integral promotion as some kind of preemptive measure against a possible overflow: you can provoke the same C4365 warning on the first line as well if you change `const unsigned short a = 0;` to `volatile unsigned short a = 0;`. But in case of the usual constants I think the compiler will not promote unless deemed necessary based on the actual known values.

Comment: Interesting. So what's actually happening is that it's giving a helpful warning about possible truncation, but is being a bit clever sometimes (when the operands are const and of known values). I notice that if I change their values such that the result can't fit in an `unsigned short`, I instead get warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'int' to 'const unsigned char'.